# Centering text with dotfill

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center

I'm writting a contract that uses dots to fill in the blank spaces when the line is finished, but also when there's a centered text. So I'm looking for a centered text that has dots at the left and the right.
Something like:
`\dotfill text \dotfill`.
I've found an approach to this but maybe there's a more efficient way:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.37 \textwidth}
        \dotfill
    \end{minipage}% 
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        TEXTSAMPLE
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\textwidth}
        \dotfill
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You actually can just write `\dotfill\ text \dotfill`. The additional backslash after the first `\dotfill` makes sure that a space is added before the text. Make sure that this line is a paragraph of its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follows, with a recent LaTeX release:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{fillcenter}{+b}
 {
  \begin{center}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \dotfill \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ \dotfill }
  \end{center}
 }
 {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\AddToHook{para/end}[dotfill]{\ifhmode\unskip\dotfill\fi}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph where the final blank space is
filled with dots.
This is a paragraph where the final blank space is
filled with dots.

\begin{fillcenter}
This is a centered \\
block where the \\
filling is on \\
either side
\end{fillcenter}

And this is again filled.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really thanks, even I don't need to write \dotfill manually! I had to upgrade my latex distro but I'm really satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 5):

A quick experiment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\dotfill TEXTSAMPLE\dotfill
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\dotfill\ TEXTSAMPLE\ \dotfill
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\textwidth}
        \dotfill
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        TEXTSAMPLE
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\textwidth}
        \dotfill
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```